# How do I get the current user's Local Settings folder path in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to point a file dialog at a particular folder in the current user's Local Settings folder on Windows.  What is the shortcut to get this path?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about this, for example:

```
String appData = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

I don't see an enum for just the Local Settings folder.

http://web.archive.org/web/20080303235606/http://dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/nenoloje/archive/2007/07/07/259223.aspx has a list with examples.

Comment: Updated it with the Internet Archive link.

Answer (score 2):

```
string localPath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)).FullName;
```

is the simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolders.LocalApplicationData);?

I can't remember if there is a "Local Settings" folder on Windows XP anymore, it seems vaguely familiar.